# Parturbations of orthonormal bases

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

Suppose that $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space $H$, and let $(f_n)$ be an orthonormal sequence in $H$ such that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|e_n-f_n\|<\infty.$$

How can one show that $(f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is also a basis in $H$.

Comment: How far have you gone?

Comment: Well, not far, I'm afraid... :( Could you give me a hint?

Comment: In many cases you will be able to identify an easy half and a difficult half of a problem.  Knowing that you identified the easy part and dispatched it tells your Readers something about the level of answer need to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\sum_{n\geqslant N} \|f_n-e_n\|^2 < 1$. We will show that $(f_k)_{k\geqslant N}$ is a basis for $\{e_k\colon k<N\}^\perp$, which will be enough. Let $f\in \{e_k\colon k<N\}^\perp$ and suppose that $(f,f_{n})=0$ for all $n\geqslant N$. I *claim* that $f=0$.

Assume not. Then
$$
\|f\|^{2}=\sum_{n\geqslant N}|(f,e_{n})|^{2}=\sum_{n\geqslant N}|(f,e_{n}-f_{n})|^{2}
\leqslant \sum_{n\geqslant N}\|f\|^{2}\|e_{n}-f_{n}\|^{2}< \|f\|^{2},
$$
which conspicuously yields a contradiction. We have then proved that $(f_k)_{k\geqslant N}$ is a basis for $\{e_k\colon k<N\}^\perp$.

Now, as $(f_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ is an orthogonal sequence, $$H = \overline{{\rm span}}\{e_k\colon k<N\}\oplus  \overline{{\rm span}}\{f_k\colon k\geqslant N\}.$$
By the uniqueness of orthogonal complements, $\overline{{\rm span}}\{e_k\colon k<N\} = \overline{{\rm span}}\{f_k\colon k<N\}$, which proves our assertion.

As a side remark, let me mention a counter-part of this statement for Banach spaces. This is the so-called principle of small perturbations due to Bessaga and Pełczyński:

> Suppose that $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a basic sequence in a Banach space $X$ having basis constant $M$ and such that the closed linear span of this sequence is complemented by a projection $P$. If $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $X$ that satisfies
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|e_n - f_n\| \leqslant \frac{1}{8M\|P\|},$$
>   then $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a basic sequence equivalent to $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ and the closed linear span of $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is complemented in $X$.

Comment: Yeah, should be $<$ instead of $\le$, sorry.